# I can't run a simple test in RIDE (ROBOT FRAMEWORK)

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I was trying to run a test I wrote in RIDE IDE
I'm using SelenuimLibrary and i'm trying to open the Linkedin login page

**Here is the code below**

```
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${Username}       swtestacademy@gmail.com
${Password}       wrongpass
${Browser}        Firefox
${SiteUrl}        http://www.linkedin.com
${DashboardTitle}    World’s Largest Professional Network | LinkedIn
${ExpectedWarningMessage}    Hmm, we don't recognize that email. Please try again.
${WarningMessage}    Login Failed!
${Delay}          5s

*** Test Cases ***
Login Should Fail With Unregistered Mail Adress
    Open LinkedinPage
    Check Title
    Enter User Name
    Enter Wrong Password
    Click Login
    sleep    ${Delay}
    Assert Warning Message
    [Teardown]    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
Open LinkedinPage
    open browser    ${SiteUrl}    ${Browser}
    Maximize Browser Window

Enter User Name
    Input Text    id=login-email    ${Username}

Enter Wrong Password
    Input Text    id=login-password    ${Password}

Click Login
    Click Button    css=[name=submit]

Check Title
    Title Should be    ${DashboardTitle}

Assert Warning Message
    Element Text Should Be    id=session_key-login-error    ${ExpectedWarningMessage}    ${WarningMessage}
```

**Here is the output I got when I hit run button** with no feedback
[image]

**Here is the full message:**

> *command: pybot.bat --argumentfile c:\users\farhat\appdata\local\temp\RIDEocku32.d\argfile.txt --listener
>   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotframework_ride-2.0a1-py2.7.egg\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:53791:False
>   "C:\Users\Farhat\Documents\My Workspace\Robot"

**Python version**

> Python 2.7.17 (v2.7.17:c2f86d86e6, Oct 19 2019, 21:01:17) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: switch execute the command from Pybot->Robot

Comment: I only have 3 option
Custom Script
jybot
pybot

Comment: try manually run your test from the command line. does it work? sound like your ride is out of date

Comment: yeah, it runs using "robot test.robot"

Comment: Solution is update your RIDE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command  Pybot is deprecated and it's removed from robot framework.Please try to use command `Robot` instead, So the solution is you need to update your ***RIDE*** because you're using old version of it.

[Find Latest Update RIDE](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-ride/)

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Ride from command line instead of opening from desktop, and run the test cases. It should work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).